# Filter json when entry key has space javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to filter json when my entry has space, example above won't work:

```
data.filter(({BUDGET TYPE}) => BUDGET TYPE === budgets[i]);
```

my `data` variable is a json that is an array that has keys 'BUDGET TYPE', but since my key has a space, I am getting the following error:

ERROR: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Can you add more code and detail to the question? In its present form it's extremely unclear what the problem is

Comment: None of that is JSON

Comment: Share your data object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question applies to JavaScript destructuring in general, it doesn't matter if it is a filter or an object that originates from JSON.

JavaScript variable names [cannot contain spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables), no matter if they are destructured or not:

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).

The proper way to destructure a property which name contains invalid characters is:

```
data.filter(({ 'BUDGET TYPE': budgetType }) => budgetType === budgets[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use destructuring here, you'll have to do it the hard way:

```
data.filter(datum => datum["BUDGET TYPE"] === budgets[i]);
```

Note that the dot access operator will fail for the same reason:

```
data.filter(datum => datum.BUDGET TYPE === budgets[i]); // ERROR!!
```

Comment: Where "hard way" is actually simpler and shorter…

Comment: @deceze yes, I'm a big fan of destructuring but it adds no value here.